# AFNetworking UIProgress view in Table Cell causes dealloc when the tableviewcontroller is navigated from

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, afnetworking

I have been implementing background uploads and downloads and using AFNetworking to handle the tasks.

Part of this is that I have a tableview that shows the current state of filetransfers.

When I create the tableview cell I add a UIProgressView (from the AFNetworking Category) to the cell.

I then assign the task for it to track the progress of like below.

```
    [taskProgressView setProgressWithDownloadProgressOfTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)self.task animated:YES];
```

However when I navigate away from the View controller that has the tableview, I get the following issue.

*** -[UIProgressView retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x65a6cced0

In the code I have tried to dealloc everything I can, setup reuse of cells, and remove any notification observers I have. However this still happens.

The only way I have managed to stop this is to not assign the task to the UIProgressView.

You can find the Category for the UIProgressView (AFNetworking here)

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIProgressView%2BAFNetworking.m

My assumption is that in there something is still retaining a reference to the progress view and not releasing it correctly.

Any suggestions of what to try next are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the AfNetworking code, when you call `setProgressWithDownloadProgressOfTask`, `self.task` is added as observer to some properties of the `UIProgressView`.

In the `dealloc` method of the cell you should stop observing the task properties.

I would suggest something like this:

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [self.task removeObserver:taskProgressView forKeyPath:@"state"];
    [self.task removeObserver:taskProgressView forKeyPath:@"countOfBytesReceived"];
}
```

It is not that good that you have to use the keyPath strings from the custom AFNetworking `UIProgressView`, the class should have also added methods to remove observers.

But I think this should solve your crash. Good luck!